# Calculate moonrise

Tags: date-and-time, astronomy

Mathematica has `Sunrise[]`, but no `Moonrise[]`. But it has `MoonPosition[]`, so I thought it would be trivial to calculate with something like

```
FindRoot[MoonPosition[DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, x}]][[2,1]], {x, 12}]
```

But the evaluation of DateObject fails in this context!

A `Table` works fine, but I cannot get it to evaluate the Dateobject in `Solve`, `NSolve`, `FindRoot` or similar.

Suggestions?

Comment: It does not fail, it just complains and at the end I get `{x -> 29.1625}`

Comment: Try with `mp[x_?NumberQ] := MoonPosition[DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, x}]][[2, 1]]` to not prompt any errors.

Comment: Take a look here: [How do I use ?NumericQ to affect order of evaluation?](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12502) and [User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/5478) which is likely a duplicate.

Comment: Just an astronomical note: moon position varies up to a degree depending where on Earth you are, and you might want to consider refraction of 34 minutes at the horizon. If you're looking for super-accuracy (matching USNO's tables), it's possible but more difficult.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
f[x_?NumberQ] := MoonPosition[DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, x}]][[2, 1]]

FindRoot[f[x], {x, 12}]
```

> {x -> 17.5595}

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, 1, 24, 0.5}], Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}]
```

[image]

So another root is at about 4:

```
FindRoot[f[x], {x, 4}]
```

> {x -> 3.7208}

Comment: Unfortunately it's extremely slow.  Because `MoonPosition` itself is so slow that it isn't really usable for such tasks ...

Comment: Thanks guys, also @Kuba! Curious, in Mathematica 10 I get {x -> 4.00933}, but I suppose this could be some rounding or insufficient resolution in MoonPosition[] (declination seem only given to 0.01 resolution)

Comment: @HJensen MoonPosition[] uses \$GeoLocation and \$TimeZone to determine your location and time zone, so from your location, the Moon's position is different, and hence FindRoot[] finds a different time for Moon rise.

Comment: @creidhne Good point! Anyway, the AngularDegree returned by `MoonPosition[]` seems to have a resolution of (only) 3-4 digits.

Comment: Trying to reproduce this in Mathematica 13.1, I get the error message that a singular Jacobian was encountered and it returns a root of the initial value I provided. Also, the ListPlot code from this answer looks different, I assume because of granularity updates to Date Objects. I thought the problems might be related. I updated the function definition to `f[x_?NumberQ] := MoonPosition[DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, x, 0, 0}]][[2, 1]]` and it restores the ListPlot behavior, but I still receive the Jacobian error.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`PlanetaryMoonData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanetaryMoonData.html):

```
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon"]["RiseTime", "Date" -> DateObject[{2016, 9, 28}]]
(* DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, 4, 8}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 2.] *)

PlanetaryMoonData["Moon"]["SetTime", "Date" -> DateObject[{2016, 9, 28}]]
(* DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, 17, 46}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 2.] *)
```

or an older function [`AstronomicalData`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AstronomicalData.html), which was superseded in version 10:

```
AstronomicalData["Moon", {"NextRiseTime", DateObject[{2016, 9, 28}]}]
(* DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, 3, 6, 9.06516}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.] *)

AstronomicalData["Moon", {"NextSetTime", DateObject[{2016, 9, 28}]}]
(* DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, 16, 43, 52.872}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.] *)
```

Two remarks: (i) `AstronomicalData` seems to give a result with finer granularity. (ii) The slight discrepancy in the results can be resolved by explicitly providing the location.

```
PlanetaryMoonData["Moon"]["RiseTime", {"Date" -> DateObject[{2016, 9, 28}], 
  "Location" -> GeoPosition[{46, 15}]}]
(* DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, 4, 6}, "Minute", "Gregorian", 2.] *)

AstronomicalData["Moon", {"NextRiseTime", DateObject[{2016, 9, 28}], {46, 15}}]
(* DateObject[{2016, 9, 28, 3, 6, 16.2692}, "Instant", "Gregorian", 1.]*)
```

Comment: Much nicer than any option so far. The Documentation indicates that AstronomicalData has been superseded by other functions. There is both PlanetaryMoonData and the PlanetaryMoon entity, the former of which basically just produces the latter. There's a slightly different syntax to accessing the information, and I think the usage in the Documentation for PlanetaryMoon might have an error. Here's what works: `PlanetaryMoonData["Moon"]["RiseTime","Date"->Now]` Which is different from the suggested usage at the top: `PlanetaryMoonData["Moon"][Dated["RiseTime",Now]]`

Comment: @Karl, thank you for your comment! I have included that in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This accepted solution appears to no longer work in Mathematica 13.1, I believe because of updates to how granularity of dates are handled.

Borrowing heavily from previous answers, I stumbled on a solution that works for me.

```
f[x_?NumberQ] := 
 MoonPosition[DateObject[{2024, 9, 28, x, 0, 0}]][[2, 1]]
minimizeResult = NMinimize[Abs[f[x]], x]
crossingHour = x /. minimizeResult[[2]]
```